# Making a sequence non-recursive

Tags: summation, notation, recurrence-relations

I have a sequence that produces outputs: 1, 4, 13, 40, 121...

I know that for the nth term, the output would be $3^0 + 3^1 + \ldots + 3^n$

But I don't know how to write this without it being recursive.

The reason it can't be recursive is because I'm doing an infinite sum.

I mainly don't know how to notate recursive in summation, but if that's possible it would work too.

To clarify, I want to plug this sequence into an infinite sum. Thank you!

Comment: This is a geometric sum. That is, a sum of the form $1+a+a^2 + \dots + a^n$.

This sum is equal to $\frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}$, in your case $a$ is $3$.

Comment: @HereToRelax . I accidentally flagged your comment and I can't figure out how to undo it.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I don't know either, but there shouldn't be any problems, especially with your new comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how to write the series

$$3^0 + 3^1 + \ldots + 3^n$$

concisely, then you can use [Sigma notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Capital-sigma_notation) to condense it to

$$3^0 + 3^1 + \ldots + 3^n = \sum_{i = 0}^n 3^i$$

However, if you're looking for a formula you can apply to the series to make it easier to calculate, then you can use the fact that $3^0, 3^1, 3^2, \ldots$ is a geometric sequence - that is, each pair of consecutive terms has a fixed ratio of 3 - and use the formula for a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series):

$$a + ar + ar^2 + \ldots + ar^n = \sum_{i = 0}^n a r^i = a\frac{r^{n+1} - 1}{r - 1}$$

where in this case, $a = 1$ and $r = 3$, so

$$3^0 + 3^1 + \ldots + 3^n = 1 \times \frac{3^{n+1} - 1}{3 - 1} = \frac{1}{2}(3^{n+1} - 1)$$